# WP_User_Query is Not Displaying Results

Tags: wp-user-query

I'm trying to create a table with a list of users and it only seems to work when I have it set up like this:

```
$user_report_query = new WP_User_Query( array(
    'role' => 'Administrator' 
) );
```

The array I'm trying to use is:

```
$args = array (
    'role'   => 'Participant',
    'order'  => 'ASC',
);
```

`Participant` is a custom role which has already been set up. I can select the role when creating users from the role dropdown menu. But any time i try to edit the query to use the array argument

```
$user_report_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

it tells me no users have been found

```
if ( ! empty( $user_report_query->results ) ) {
    //display users
} else { 
    echo 'No users found.';
}
```

It only seems to work when I have the role as Administrator. As far as I can tell this is a basic WordPress user query so i shouldn't be having any problems with it. Any idea what it might be?

Comment: What action hook are you adding your custom user role on - and does this fire before any query you run to retrieve user records?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example of a user query I'm using that is working. Please note that I am using the `role__in` argument instead of the `role` argument. I'm not sure why the `role` argument wouldn't work for you but I know this code works so hopefully it will work for you as well.

```
$args = array(
    'role__in' => array('Subcriber', 'Editor'),
); // End Args
if ($args){
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
}
```